# AChartEngine as View is not displayed

Tags: android, android-layout, achartengine

I have a LiveChart. I add it as a view to a Linealayout. But I can't see it when the app is running. This is my code:

```
view = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(this, dataset, renderer, "Live View");
view.refreshDrawableState();
view.repaint();

linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
linearLayout.addView(view, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layout params may be wrong for the chart view. I sugges you use `FILL_PARENT` for width and `WRAP_CONTENT` for height.

Comment: I changed it. But my soloution was to copy the xml file and use the new one. I have no idea why it is now working. But thanks for your help!